# preg_replace(): "non-strict" replacement

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, string-parsing

I have some string `$content`, which contains some px-metrics (`"<div class="predefined" data-key="name" style="z-index: 1000; position: absolute; max-width: 556px; width: 556px;..."`). I need to multiply every found metric by some number.

I decided to use `preg_replace()`:

1) for first argument - patterns - I parsed string and got `$patterns` array with all px-metrics in string; after that added for every element delimiters `"/"`:

```
$patterns = array (
  0 => '/556px/',
  1 => '/556px/',
  2 => '/40px/',
  3 => '/1px/',
  4 => '/1px/',
  5 => '/556px/',
  6 => '/556px/',
  7 => '/40px/',
  8 => '/1px/',
  9 => '/280px/',
  10 => '/556px/',
  11 => '/20px/',
  12 => '/100px/',
  13 => '/40px/',
  14 => '/220px/',
  15 => '/480px/',
);
```

2) second argument - `$replacements` - should be every metric from $patterns, multiplied by some num (in this case, num is 2.6978417266187051):

```
$replacements = array (
  0 => '1500px',
  1 => '1500px',
  2 => '107.91366906475px',
  3 => '2.6978417266187px',
  4 => '2.6978417266187px',
  5 => '1500px',
  6 => '1500px',
  7 => '107.91366906475px',
  8 => '2.6978417266187px',
  9 => '755.39568345324px',
  10 => '1500px',
  11 => '53.956834532374px',
  12 => '269.78417266187px',
  13 => '107.91366906475px',
  14 => '593.52517985612px',
  15 => '1294.964028777px',
);
```

3) run `$content = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $content);`

I noticed problem with element[14]. There is a peace of result string:

`height: 107.91366906475px; bottom: auto; left: 253.956834532374px; top: 1294.964028777px;">111222</div>`

`left`, which should be *593.52517985612px*, is *253.956834532374px*! I see, why it occurs:

*2**20px*** is replaced not by 15-th element, but particially by element[11] (*2**20px*** => 2 + replace by element[11] => *2**53.956834532374px***).

What can I do with that? My reg. expressions in `$patterns` are not in brackets, so I was waiting for strict comparison.

If it cannot be resolved, I can use totally another approach for changing metrics in string, not exactly via `preg_replace()`, any help will be useful.

Comment: use `preg_replace_callback` with a general pattern

Comment: Also note that `str_replace()` works with arrays as well. But you're better off not building the arrays in the first place.

Comment: @miken32, thanks, using `str_replace()` is even better decision, then accepted, if I have patterns like strict strings (for ex., `{{Category Name}}`) and not like `{{.+}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments, [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) allows you to execute code on the matched text, similar to PCRE's `e` flag:

```
$content = preg_replace_callback(
    "/(\d+)px/",
    function($g) {
        $val = $g[1] * 2.6978417266187051;
        return $val . "px";
    }, $content
);
```